# How Save UILocalNotifications in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode7, nsdata, uilocalnotification

Answer is below, image is here:

[image]

Comment: Please put the answer in an actual answer to your question and accept it. Nice start at StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Oh yes I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for directly adding the image @Kametrixom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching how to do this for a couple of days and was only able to find people who stored *UILocalNotificaations* in *NSUserDefaults*. Saving these in *NSUserDefaults* seemed wrong to me because it is supposed to be used for small flags. I just now finally figured out how to store notifications in **CoreData**. This is Using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2

First off you need to create a new **entity** in your CoreDataModel
and then add a single attribute to it. the attribute should be of type **Binary Data** I named my table/entity "ManagedFiredNotifications" and my attribute "notification". it should look like this:

**Image linked in Question above.**

Next you need to add an extension to *UILocalNotification* it should go like this:

```
extension UILocalNotification { 
   func save() -> Bool {
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
      let firedNotificationEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ManagedFiredNotifications", inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate!.managedObjectContext)

      guard appDelegate != nil else {
         return false
      }

      let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)

      firedNotificationEntity.setValue(data, forKey: "notification")

      do {
         try appDelegate!.managedObjectContext.save()
         return true
      } catch {
         return false
      }
   }
}
```

Now for saving a notification all you need to do is call

```
UILocalNotification.save()
```

On the notification you would like to save. my notifications were named 'notification' so I would call notification.save()

To retrieve a notification you need a method like this

```
func getLocalFiredNotifications() -> [UILocalNotification]? {
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)!.managedObjectContext
    let firedNotificationFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ManagedFiredNotifications")
    firedNotificationFetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false

    do {
        let fetchedFiredNotifications = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(firedNotificationFetchRequest)
        guard fetchedFiredNotifications.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }


        var firedNotificationsToReturn = [UILocalNotification]()
        for managedFiredNotification in fetchedFiredNotifications {

            let notificationData = managedFiredNotification.valueForKey("notification") as! NSData
            let notificationToAdd = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(notificationData) as! UILocalNotification

            firedNotificationsToReturn.append(notificationToAdd)
        }
        return firedNotificationsToReturn
    } catch {
        return nil
    }

}
```

Note that this returns an array of UILocalNotifications.

When retrieving these if you plan on removing a few of them and then storing the list again you should remove them when you get them something like this works:

```
func loadFiredNotifications() {
    let notifications = StudyHelper().getLocalFiredNotifications()
    if notifications != nil {
        firedNotifications = notifications!
    } else {
        // throw an error or log it
    }
    classThatRemoveMethodIsIn().removeFiredLocalNotifications()
}
```

I hope this helps someone who had the same problems that I did trying to implement this.